# Duda con parámetros de props en componente: destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Mi duda es la siguiente, estoy aprendiendo React y estoy en la parte de los componentes y pasando props a estos mismos, resulta que el primer ejemplo que realicé lo tengo de la siguiente forma.

```
    export function Props ({listItem, name = '- No pertenece a nadie -'}) {
    return <li>{listItem}, pertenece a {name}</li>

    <Props listItem="Testing 1" name="Bastian" />
    <Props listItem="Testing 2" name="Antonia" />
    <Props listItem="Testing 3" name="Rocio" />
    <Props listItem="Testing 4" />


}
```

Lo que comprendí es que, como primera parte estoy exportando mi componente hacía el archivo correspondiente de index.js. Lo que estoy haciendo es nombré una variable listItem y otra name, la cuál esta llamada name, si es que no se le pasa ningún parámetro adquirirá el valor por defecto de 'No pertenece a nadie'. Luego lo que hago es darle los valores a las variables listItem y name. Hasta acá ninguna duda y esto en el navegador se imprime bien.

Luego de eso creo un componente llamado InfoBancario para pasarle más parámetros (a forma de reforzar lo aprendido).

```
export function InfoBancario (props){
    return <div>
        <ul>
            <li>El dueño de la cuenta es {props.nombre}. El dinero que tiene es {props.montoDinero} USD. ¿Se encuentra habilitado para pedir un credito? {props.situacion ? 'Si' : 'No'}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
<InfoBancario nombre="Bastian" montoDinero={3000} situacion={true} />
```

La duda que tengo es la siguiente. Resulta que al querer pasar los parámetros como lo hice con el primer componente este no me deja y no se impremen por pantalla, los quería pasar de esta forma:

```
export function InfoBancario (nombre, montoDinero, situacion){
    return <div>
        <ul>
            <li>El dueño de la cuenta es {nombre}. El dinero que tiene es {montoDinero} USD. ¿Se encuentra habilitado para pedir un credito? {situacion ? 'Si' : 'No'}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Al momento de querer realizarlo así, estos dejan de imprimirse por pantalla y la consola marca error, no así el código. Creo saber por qué es pero me gustaría saber si es que estoy en lo correcto o si me pudieran dar una mejor explicación. ¿Es por qué ya no estoy pasando solo Strings y estoy pasando booleanos y int, lo considera como si fuera un objeto?

Answer (score 1):

Mil disculpas, acabo de descubrir que si puedo pasarlos como yo quería sin necesidad de poner props, solo tenia que poner las llaves.

```
export function InfoBancario ({nombre, montoDinero, situacion}){
    return <div>
        <ul>
            <li>El dueño de la cuenta es {nombre}. El dinero que tiene es {montoDinero} USD. ¿Se encuentra habilitado para pedir un credito? {situacion ? 'Si' : 'No'}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Se llama object destructuring, como complemento a tus estudios [Destructuring Props on react](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructuring-of-props-in-reactjs/)

Comment: Muchas gracias!